# Unable to select all the items in the UI-Grid selenium C#

Tags: c#, angularjs, selenium

I am able to select the first checkbox in the UI-Grid and the selecting of all the items at a time or looping throgh the list is not happnening, But when I debug the code and verified the click works on all the items in the list.

Below is related HTML code:

```
//Html Code of Checkbox
<div class="ui-grid-selection-row-header-buttons ui-grid-icon-ok ng-scope"
     ng-class="{'ui-grid-row-selected': row.isSelected}" 
     ng-click="selectButtonClick(row, $event)" 
     role="button" 
     tabindex="0">&nbsp;</div>

//HTML Code of Button
<button class="dowbutton float_right ng-scope" 
        ng-if="technologyName != 'gtone' " ng-
        click="checkoutSelectedApplication()">Checkout/Update</button>
```

Below is my code to loop through the list and select the items in the list:

```
IList elements = driver.FindElements(
     By.XPath("//div[@ng-click='selectButtonClick(row, $event)']")).ToList();

int numberOfElements=elements.Count();
var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(
     By.XPath("//div[@ng-click='selectButtonClick(row, $event)']"))).Click();


for (int i = 0; i < numberOfElements; i++)
{
    elements = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//div[@ng-click='selectButtonClick(row, $event)']"));
    elements.ElementAt(i).Click();
}
```

After click of the checkbox, it will not fire any event. But after click the button it will happen.

I am able to click on the first checkbox and then click on the button succesfully, but not able to continue click the second checkbox and the button

My goal is to click the first checkbox and then button and after that continue with second checkbox and the button and so on..Till the end of all the checkbox in the list.

Any help on these would be more appreciated....

Answer (score 0):

When you manual select the checkbox, did something happen on page? like partial page refresh/loading. If so, you need to wait a little before select the next checkbox.

Sleep 5 seconds after `elements.ElementAt(i).Click();`, if sleep work fine, try below code:

```
String cssSelector = "div[ng-click*='selectButtonClick']";

IList elements = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector(cssSelector)).ToList();

var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
int numberOfElements=elements.Count(); 

for (int i = 0; i < numberOfElements; i++)
{
    // click checkbox
    elements.ElementAt(i).Click();

    // click button
    driver.FindElement(
        By.CssSelector("button[ng-click*='checkoutSelectedApplication']")).Click();

    // wait page refresh/load complete  
    wait.Until(ExpectedConditions
             .ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector(cssSelector)));

    // find all checkbox again, because page changed,
    // otherwise report StaleReference
    elements = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector(cssSelector));
}
```

Comment: Please show your HTML code of checkboxs and the button you mentioned

Comment: Hi Yong,I posted my HTML for button and checkbox please find